# spl_autoload_register confusion on require

Tags: php, class, spl-autoload-register

So I've read some of this `PHP` function, and I understand how to instantiate it, though I am having difficulties understanding the use case and possibly the functionality of the `spl_autoload_register` function. So here is what I have

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once "classes/{$class}.php";
});
```

But my question is if my `classes` directory looks like this

```
-Security.php
-Zipper.php
-Functions.php
-Sanitize.php
-Extract.php
```

And if my page does not need every single one of these does it actually `require` the classes? Or does it only `require` when it is called like so

```
new Zipper;
```

Please help me to clarify this confusion of the `spl_autoload_register` function.
Also does naming conventions work? Say if I try instantiating `new Hashing;` and that belongs to `Security.php` how exactly would it know how to `require` that file, or like I said does naming conventions help?

**Example**

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    switch($class) {
      case "Booger":
      case "booger": $class = "Snot";
    }
    require_once "classes/{$class}.php";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spl_autoload_register` will only allow the class to *possibly* be available instead of erroring out -- it doesn't actually instantiate the class.

What you do in the callback is up to you. Your "Security.php" class file should look something like:

```
class Security {
  [...]
}
```

Whatever file you include, such as `require_once "classes/{$class}.php";` means that the file name AND class name in the file must match `$class`.

Comment: I know it doesn't instantiate the class itself. Like I said I get that function per say, just not the whole working of it. But I believe you've clarified it. If I don't write `require 'Security.php'` and i try using it the `spl_autoload_register` will help and try to do what I write in the closure above in my example, correct?

Comment: Correct.. assuming the file exists with the class name you're using.. it's like a "load this class file on demand" instead of doing a bunch of `require` lines.

Comment: Ok just got your update so naming conventions need to be exact. So in my closure I can write a switch case off of the `$class` correct if I was wanting to, hypothetically.

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the closure. It might be a better practice to follow PSR-1, PSR-2, etc. standards... or even use namespaces that match folder hierarchies.

Comment: Got ya, just one last question and I'll mark you up. I added an example above, is that the way I would go about it just for examples that is all.

Comment: That's fine, as long as `class Booger` exists in `classes/Snot.php` - but this doesn't make sense. Ideally, your class names should match your file names somehow. For very small projects, I would usually do something like `classes/ClassName.class.php` and then require it as `require "classes/{$class}.class.php"` so that I was sure it was a class file. There's a ton of ways to do this, however.

Comment: Thanks Half Crazed. You've actually made this a lot easier for me to understand, it's first time using this and was tired of requiring everything and just found it today. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

`spl_autoload_register` is called whenever you initiate a class that isn't available in memory. It's really a safety net to tell the engine where to look for the class if it's not already loaded. So a certain file is only included when you use the class for the first time in the script.

---

You could write conditional statements about which file to include but that's not a very clean way to use the method.

The most useful use-case is to create a file for each class by a certain naming convention. This makes it easier for you and others to find a class in your project at a later time.